# Import large CSV file in mysql by disable/enable constraints and indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to import large CSV file in  database table.I am using **"Mysql"** as a database.My table has **"Innodb"** engine and I am importing CSV file by using following command:

```
`LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE......`
```

My senior suggested me to use this command in following order to import CSV file in faster way:

1. Disable or drop the indexes.
2. Disable or drop constraints.
3. Fire load data command
4. Enable or recreate constraints
5. Enable or recreate indexes.

I have one primary key with auto-increment,two foreign keys and one unique index on two column.

As I new to database,I have searched on internet for how to enable/disable constraints? From that I can able to understand that

1. Primary key has one unique index internally with not null constrain
2. Foreign key has one index internally with not null constraint.
3. Also by using **"SET foreign_key_checks = 0"** command we can able to disable the foreign key,but it will disable the all the foreign keys checking of database instead of single table so I want it for single table.
4. I can able to disable unique index by using **"ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE ALL KEYS"** command.

So I have following doubt :

1. Can I able to disable foreign key constrain of particular table and after disable it will also disable index internally or I have to drop it.
2. Can I able to disable primary key with auto-increment and after disable it will also disable unique index internally or I have to drop it but I want auto-increment for first column i.e for primary key as CSV file don't have first column value.

Can anybody help me out to solve this problem, Thanks.

Comment: the syntax is: ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE KEYS 
and it does not disable unique indices

Answer (score 1):

Disabling key constraints from a table before importing more data from a CSV file may speed up the import, but if you are not 100% sure that the newly imported CSV data is not in violation of the key constraints, it you may be unable to recreate the dropped KEYs after import.

1. If the first column of the imported data has value NULL, importing it will cause Mysql to create a sequence number of new unique PRIMARY KEYs. If you drop the AUTO_INCREMENTING PRIMARY KEY, this nice feature will be disabled, and your data will be without a primary key. There are many workarounds around this, but most of these will consume more time and computing resaources than just leaving the PRIMARY KEY on during import.